# Function that involved several steps of computation

Tags: functions, function-construction

I basically want to put a whole calculation that I do to find the second derivative of a function into a Mathematica > Function.

This is what I have:

```
(* Definition of 2nd partial derivative and Hessian matrix *)

{dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = 
  D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}}]; (* calculating partial derivatives *) 
hes[x_, y_] = 
  D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}];(* Hessian matrix: Second derivative matrix *)

(*Extrema *)

(* Find critical points *)
crit = Cases[
   Normal[ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
     PlotPoints -> 100, ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
     MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]], 
   Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> ({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
      FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], 
        dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]}, {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], 
         y0}}]), \[Infinity]];

(* Identify points as minima, maxima or saddle points *)
hl = hes @@@ crit;
mnp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hl; (*pick minima*)
mxp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ (-hl); (*pick maxima*)
sdp = Thread[mnp \[Nor] mxp];(*saddle points are leftovers*)

(* Finding coordinates of critical points *)
mini = Pick[crit, mnp];
maxi = Pick[crit, mxp];
sadl = Pick[crit, sdp];
z1 = mini;
a1 = IIges @@@ mini;
b1 = hes @@@ mini;
z2 = maxi;
a2 = IIges @@@ maxi;
b2 = hes @@@ maxi;
```

Where IIges[x,y] is the function I want to differentiate and xm is the window size over which it finds extremal points.

I want all of this to be included in a Function along the lines of

```
 FindExtrema[IIges[x,y], xm]
```

which returns

```
z1, a1, b1, z2, a2, b2
```

somehow.

Is this possible?

Comment: [Module](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) + links we gave you in your last question.

Comment: I am not even sure whether it is possible to do. Usually functions are f[x_,y_] := x^2 + y^2. Do you think it's possible to use the same syntax ( f[sth] := ) for something that has many steps and then returns values not directly related to the input arguments?

Comment: You would usually make `x` and `y` arguments of `FindExtrema` too.  See e.g. second argument in Minimize: `Minimize[f[x], x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code

```
FindExtrema[IIges_, xm_] := 
 Module[{dx, dy, x, y, \[FormalX], \[FormalY], hes, crit, hl, mnp, mxp, sdp, mini, maxi, sadl, z1, a1, b1, z2, a2, b2},
  {dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}}];
  hes[x_, y_] = D[IIges[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}];
  crit = Cases[
    Normal[ContourPlot[dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -xm, xm}, {y, -xm, xm}, 
      PlotPoints -> 100, ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
      MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]], 
    Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> ({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
       FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], 
         dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]}, {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], 
          y0}}]), ∞];
  hl = hes @@@ crit;
  mnp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hl;
  mxp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ (-hl);
  sdp = Thread[mnp ⊽ mxp];
  mini = Pick[crit, mnp];
  maxi = Pick[crit, mxp];
  sadl = Pick[crit, sdp];
  {z1 = mini, a1 = IIges @@@ mini, b1 = hes @@@ mini, z2 = maxi, 
   a2 = IIges @@@ maxi, b2 = hes @@@ maxi}
  ]
```

Define `f[x_, y_]` and `xm` and call `FindExtrema[f, xm]`

The function returns a list of variables in order specified inside the [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html)

Comment: Thanks, why did you not include dx and dy in the initial curly brackets? Which variables go there?

Comment: or x, y and hl for that matter

Comment: @SuperCiocia they all should be there -- tells _Mathemtica_ to treat them as local variables not to be confused with variables with the same names defined outside of `Module`. Updated the answer.